# How to correctly add an icon to JButton in Java?

Tags: java, unicode, fonts, jbutton

I am trying to add this [icon](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f6a9/index.htm) to a button in my minesweeper application. However, instead of having the icon, I get an empty square. Here's the code I'm using: (The code was used just to test if I can actually can add the icon to a button)

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                JButton button = new JButton("\uD83D\uDEA9");
                Font font = new Font("Code2000", Font.PLAIN, 12);
                button.setFont(font);
                frame.add(button);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);           
            });
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your font support it? Not every font has glyphs for all codes

Comment: @BackSlash, I am not sure, I just used the font I found on some other question. I'll try to look for other fonts. Thanks

Comment: You might want to take a look [here](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f6a9/fontsupport.htm)

Comment: The other thing you can do is make an image of that glyph (take a screen shot and crop it) and then just load it as an image.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an ImageIcon to the Button

```
JButton button = new JButton();
ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(Directory);
button.setIcon(image);
```

A very simple solution!